# Multipatch multiple slice for creating building floors?

Tags: arcgis-pro, multipatch

I'm searching for a method to create multiple horizontal slices at set intervals on a multipatch object.

The slice function in Argis Pro allows only for one horizontal (or vertical) slice to be made, and it is not possible to set a numerical value for the placement of the actual slice.

I'm trying to establish floors in a multipatch object representing a building. I've investigated the "3D Basemap" approach, but this is far too extensive, and not suitable for my project.

There must be a relatively simple way to achieve this either through scripting, or other methods?